# Gitversion increment last digit in AssemblyInfo

Tags: gitversion

I'm using [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/msbuild-task/) to automatically create version information for my C# applications.

Does anybody know if Gitversion is able to increment the last digit of the `AssemblyFileVersion` (in AssemblyInfo.cs) in case you're on a feature branch?

The [docu](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/msbuild-task/) states the following:

> AssemblyFileVersion will be set to the MajorMinorPatch variable with .0 appended to it.

So the last digit will always be 0. Anyhow the docu could be outdated. I would be cool if the last digit gets incremented by one (or inject the number of commits since the last tag) if you're on e.g. a feature branch.

Based on that you could:

- distinct multiple artifact versions of a feature branch, since the last digit increments.
- Avoid MSI installer problem, since e.g. the file version of an exe never changes on a feature branch. So the Windows installer won't update a dll or exe since the version hasn't changed (in case of Windows installer uses all 4 digits for comparing operations).

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the format of AssemblyFileVersion in GitVersion.yml

```
assembly-file-versioning-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}.{CommitsSinceVersionSource}'
```

That would put the number of commits since the last label into the 4th version part

Here's all the variables you can use:

https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input/docs/more-info/variables/

Answer (score -1):

GitVersion's goal is to allow you to easily calculate a Semantic Version number for your code, according to [SemVer2.0](https://semver.org) (with a bit of legacy NuGet versioning mixed in, in case you need to deal with older v2 NuGet binary resource managers).

So in short, no, GitVersion isn't able to automatically increment the revision field of the assembly file version because that 4th version part isn't part of SemVer.